# Android : Error retrieving parent for item

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, gradle

I am using this `compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.3.0'`  library and when I compile it with gradle it gives me this error

`Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.`

`Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.`

Source : https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView

Please help me solve it and tell me why this is happening

Comment: Please give me a reason for negative votes, don't waste my question doing unnecessary negative vote

Comment: The reason your question is being downvoted is because it is very hard to understand what you want to do. Please include sample code that generates the error that you've included. The link to your git repo is insufficient because it does not meet our requirements of a minimally verifiable example.

Comment: You can do this without downvoting my ans, so that other can ans that who understand it better

Comment: Ah, except I didn't downvote your answer. Someone else did, I felt it important to respond to your question about what you can improve so that you can fix your question. I also hate being downvoted without being given a reason, so I usually give feedback. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to help edit your question. If you do so, someone just might upvote your question to counter the downvote.

Comment: @JasonD Thanx four your feedback, I didn't want to be mean, I just eagerly waiting for my answer

Comment: No worries, but I would seriously edit your question now with code. There's a risk it will get closed as it is now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96610/discussion-between-jason-d-and-ravi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This library has this dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
```

> Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

The reason of this issue is your compileSdk.
**The appcompat v23 requires**

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```

**There is a general rule for support libraries:**

**The library major version number is the minimun compile sdk version.**